# Not able to switch to parent page if child page is self closing in Karate

Tags: karate

I am stucked with following flow in Karate feature testcase

1. Open parent page
2. Click on hyperlink which opens another page
3. Switch to new page
4. Click on hyperlink which causes it to self close
5. Try to switch back to prior page

Somehow I am getting timeout exception with no reply.

Please let me know if I need to submit small piece of code for this.

Comment: sounds like a duplicate of https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/issues/2032 - right now we don't consider it a priority, so if you can investigate or even contribute a PR that would be awesome

Comment: @PeterThomas any pointers will be of geat help. I will try for solution.